# Blocking a row to enter a table when it satisfies a condition using triggers

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table practise_one with two columns ID and NAME and data as following,

ID    name :
  1 sammy,
  2 vam,
  3 mam,
  4 pam,
  5 jam,

I have defined an autonomous trigger after insert or update or delete on the table for each row.

I want all the id that are greater than 8 and are inserted into the table practise_one to be filtered out (to not be inserted into the table) only id's less than 8 can be inserted into the table. All the id's greater than 8 should be inserted into a different table practise_one_log.

My Approach of trigger:

```
create or replace trigger tr_practise_one 
after insert or update or delete on practise_one
for each row
Declare
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
  id_greater exception;
  id_one number(10);
begin
  if (:new.id>8) then
   rollback;
   raise id_greater;
  end if;
exception 
  when id_greater then
  insert into practise_one_log values('The Id is greater '||:new.id);
  commit;
end tr_practise_one;
```

When I do :

```
insert into practise_one values (9,'oam');
```

I am able to get the respective row into the table 'practise_one_log' but still I am unable to stop the row from getting into the table practise_one.

```
Resultant Output:

  ID    name :
  1 sammy,
  2 vam,
  3 mam,
  4 pam,
  5 jam,
  9     oam

Expected Output

  ID    name :
  1 sammy,
  2 vam,
  3 mam,
  4 pam,
  5 jam
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not creating a view and an instead-of trigger on the view?  I'm guessing this is a homework assignment?  If so, what are the restrictions/ requirements?  Also, you've tagged this for MySQL and Oracle 11g.  The code appears to be PL/SQL so I'm not seeing where MySQL comes in to play...

Comment: Are you allowed to switch the type of trigger you're creating? An `AFTER` trigger fires (as it's name implies) after the change has already been applied to the table. An `INSTEAD OF` trigger would mean that you're not trying to *undo* work that the database engine has already completed.

Comment: Sorry For mysql part, I didn't notice it cause I was in a hurry... I am just trying to experiment on trigger...Well I dont want to use views, Is there any approach to do the same without creating views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BEFORE trigger or INSTEAD OF.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm